# CS-Cart ignoring manifest file in my theme

Tags: cs-cart

I am using CS-Cart 4.3.6 and have created a new theme based on the responsive theme. My problem is it seems to completely ignore the locations I set in the manifest file:

```
{
  "title": "Example Theme",
  "description": "Theme for Example",
  "logo": "media/images/cart.png",
  "mail": "media/images/invoice_logo.png",
  "favicon": "media/images/favicon.ico",
  "parent_theme": "responsive"
}
```

I have put my own cart, invoice, and favicon logos within my theme images folder which is clearly set in the abbove manifest, yet it still uses the default cs-cart logos.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure that the root directory of this is located in the themes_repository and not in the "design" folder.

Otherwise make sure that you have the correct file extension (manifest.json).

Make sure the mark-up of the manifest.json looks as follows:

```
{
    "title" : "XXX",
    "description" : "XXX",
    "logo" : "XXX",
    "mail": "XXX",
    "developer" : "XXX",
    "favicon" : "XXX",
    "parent_theme": "responsive"
}
```

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of using the `var/themes_repository` directory. Should my whole theme be located here as well as `/design` ? or just the manifest file? Or should I not use `/design` at all ? All the tutorials say to create the theme in `/design` so you can understand my confusion...